# how it gonna be the associations between the models with Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, sequelize.js, node-modules

[Hi guys can someone help to make the right associations between the models with Sequelize
In my project, there are three types of product and each type got different attributes and similar attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lboo.jpg)

Hi guys can someone help to make the right associations between the models with Sequelize?
In my project, there are three types of product and each type got different attributes and similar attributes

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of relation you want between your models, from the pic it looks like product model has FK of all track, lyrics, artwork, is it??

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation for association in Sequelize [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html)

In Product model

```js
Product.associate = (models) => {
    Product.hasMany(models.Lyrics, {
      foreignKey: 'LyricsID', // FK name in Product
      sourceKey: 'id' // FK name in lyrics table
    });
    // here write same for other models (track, artwork)
    
    // for User relation where product belongs to User,
    Product.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: { name: 'UserID', allowNull: false },
      targetKey: 'UserID', // PK name from user table
      allowNull: false
    });
};
```

In User model

```js
User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.Product, {
      foreignKey: 'UserID',
      sourceKey: 'UserID'
    });
};
```